# How to avoid the line break in my column-headings?

Tags: latex

I want to create a table with (at least) 6 columns. Right now, I automatically get a line break after 4 columns and i don't know how to avoid it.

I thought I'd already have my solution with /resizebox, but obviously it doesn't change anything.

```
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Evaluationstabelle}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{cccc}\toprule
\textbf{Anzahl Features}    &\textbf{Entfernte Features} &\textbf{Filter} &\textbf{Precision} &\textbf{Recall} &\textbf{F-Score}    \\
\midrule
08.05.      & Ausarbeitung  & Formuliere & Bsp & ok & shit \\[20pt]



\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

This is how it looks right now:
[image]

But I'd want all Columns in one line. If it doesn't fit, maybe by reducing the font size or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you do, don't use `\resizebox` for elements that contain text, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text for more details.

One possibility would be to use a `tabularx` and let latex decide on the best columns widths and linebreaks. In case this is not enough to fit your table in your available textwidth, this can be combined with a smaller font (commented in the code below)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{YY}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Evaluationstabelle}
%\small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}YYYYYY@{}}
\toprule
\thead{Anzahl Features} & \thead{Entfernte Features} &\thead{Filter} &\thead{Precision} & \thead{Recall} & \thead{F-Score}\\
\midrule
08.05.      & Ausarbeitung  & Formuliere & Bsp & ok & test\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]